# Coefficients of Linear Model are way too large/low

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, data-analysis

During implementing a linear regression model on a bag of words, python returned very large/low values. `train_data_features` contains all words, which are in the training data. The training data contains about 400 comments of each less than 500 characters with a ranking between 0 and 5. Afterwards, I created a bag of words for each document. While trying to perform a linear regression on the matrix of all bag of words,

```
from sklearn import linear_model 
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(train_data_features, train['dim_hate'])

coef = clf.coef_
words = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

for i in range(len(words)):
    print(str(words[i]) + " " + str(coef[i]))
```

the result seems to be very strange (just an example of 3 from 4000). It shows the factors of the created regression function for the words.

```
btw -0.297473967075
land 54662731702.0
landesrekord -483965045.253
```

I'm very confused because the target variable is between 0 and 5, but the factors are so different. Most of them have very high/low numbers and I was expecting only values like the one of `btw`.

Do you have an idea, why the results are like they are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be that your model is overfitting to the data, since it's trying to exactly match the outputs. You're right to be worried and suspicious, because it means that your model is probably overfitting to your data and will not generalize well to new data. You can try one of two things:

- Run `LinearRegression(normalize=True)` and see if it helps with the coefficients. But it will only be a temporary solution.
- Use [Ridge regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge) instead. It is basically doing Linear Regression, except adding a penalty for having coefficients that are too large.

Comment: I've just tried. Seems, that the first option does not change much. The second gives nice and small values for each word. This seems to be a good idea. But I've to check in detail, what a ridge regression is doing, to understand the differences. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For reformatting train_data_features I'm using the package re. As soon as I add the German Umlaut 'Ü' as a capital letter to the allowed character set, the model is overfitting the results. All other Umlaute(äöüÄÖ) don't cause the same problem. What going on in the background?

Comment: Why are you reformatting `train_data_features`? When you are using `RidgeRegression` you also might need to play with the `C` value to not overfit.

Answer (score 5):

Check for correlated features in your data-set.

You may run into the problem if your features are highly correlated.  For example expenses per customer -
`jan_expenses, feb_expenses, mar_expenses, Q1_expenses` 
the Q1 feature is the sum of the jan-mar and therefore your coefficients, when trying to fit, will go 'crazy' as it will struggle to find a line that best describes the monthly features and the Q feature.   Try and remove the highly correlated features and re-run.

(btw Ridge regression also solved the problem for me but I was curious as to why this happens so i dug in a bit)